Transparent Flexible display with good definition
I'm looking for any technology (not a specific model, which would be against the SO rules) which would allow a display with the following properties:

transparent (would be used on some kind of windows)
"high" definition (meaning not pixels with space between them) with high black intensity
possibly monochrome (does not need color)
quite flexible
quite small (so any flexible led display with leds spaced by inches is off topic)

I can't find any technology that would allow to create a screen that fit those requirements...
I have seen some oled display but either TV sized or not transparent or not flexible. Same for LCD... E-ink does not seem to be transparent etc.
Any idea?
to be more specific, I'm not looking for answers indicating some specific model, but for technologies I could search

Usually stackexchange sites discourage opinion based questions. That said, LCD can be transparent but being made from layers are difficult to bend (bendable != permanently curved). OLEDs can be thinner and likely make up most (all?) of the bendable display market. But you don't like tech that blocks light. So doesn't look like the market has COTS solutions for you.

thanks, yes I'm not looking for opinion based answer, but for tech meeting some requirements
Thanks for you answer, it doesn't smell good for this search right now...

Agreed, it doesn't. And most of what I read has changed little over the past several years. Indicating no great movement toward better transparent flexible displays. Instead, the market appears to be driving toward a more durable (not transparent) OLED flexible display. Mostly because of the cell phone market.

The technology used in Liquid crystal 'privacy' film may meet most of your requirements except for contrast. It uses transparent electrodes on the insides of two flexible plastic membranes. The active material sandwiched between them switches between a milky translucent state and transparent.

I do not think this answer works for the OP. They required some type of pixel display. COTS liquid crystal "privacy" film is generally a "single pixel". That is, the transparency of the entire liquid crystal sheet is either on or off.

@st2000 the OP is looking for a technology, not a product.

Yes. Agreed. But adding pixels to your suggestion turns it into the common LCD, more or less. Which gets back to dealing with multiple layers alignment and excessive stress at the edges.
